# Function that returns referencie to function

Tags: c++, lambda, reference

I want to create function like this:

```
using MyFuncType = std::function<ReturnType(const ArgType)>;

const  MyFuncType &getConstRef(const ReturnType t){

}
```

I mean function that takes ReturnType argument and CREATES and RETURNS const reference to function that returns ReturnType; 
My attempts:

```
#include <functional>

using MyFuncType = std::function<ReturnType(const ArgType)>;

const  MyFuncType &getConstRef(const ReturnType t){
    auto *l = new MyFuncType([=](const ReturnType) { return t; }); //i want to return arg in this func
    return std::ref(*l);
}
```

Then i need to run some function like this:

```
someFunc(const MyFuncType& f)
```

And my code makes "undefined reference to someFunc". I assume because of types mismatching.
What is the correct way to create function in another function and return const ref? (

Comment: Please show the whole code. You haven’t defined `someFunc` anywhere in these snippets so it’s understandable it would be undefined

Comment: I got some .h files atached to this problem and there is ```void
someFunc(const MyFuncType& f);``` exacly sth like this ( implementation is 100% correct and i can't change it - thats part of problem spec)

Comment: Show the code. Preferably make a [mcve]. We can’t know what “some files” have and “something like” doesn’t help at all. Specific code and specific error is needed to know what is happening.

Comment: @ziyiyituxe I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Seems like all you really need is something like `MyFuncType getFunc(const ReturnType t){ return [=](const ArgType) { return t; }); }`, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should be completely valid.

https://godbolt.org/z/NpM9eZ

Make sure whatever you're referencing doesn't outlive the actual data :)